# Mapstruct conversion from Date to LocalDatetime

Tags: java, spring-boot, date, mapstruct, localdatetime

I'm trying to convert an object using a mapper with Mapstruct that has a Date (java.util.Date) field to an object with a LocalDateTime field. The problem is that it maps the time wrong because in the object with the LocalDateTime field it always says 2 hours less.

```
@Mapping(source = "createdDate", target = "createdLocalDateTime")
ObjectA toEntity(ObjectB);
```

I think that the problem is the auto implementation:

```
if ( createdDate!= null ) {
        objectA.createdLocalDateTime( LocalDateTime.ofInstant( createdDate.toInstant(), ZoneId.of( "UTC" ) ) );
    }
```

How can I fix this? Thanks!

Comment: `LocalDateTime` is the **wrong class** to use here. A `java.util.Date` object represents a point on the timeline, a date with time-of-day as seen with an offset from UTC of zero hours-minutes-seconds. In contrast, `LocalDateTime` lacks the context of an offset or time zone. You **should be using `java.time.Instant`** as the replacement for `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is already [a conversation about this on the mapstruct issues tracker](https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/2606#issuecomment-944904599). There they talk about losing a day, but the cause and solution are similar:

> The solution that you can do and is super trivial is to provide you own way of mapping between Date to LocalDate.
>
> e.g.

```java
public class DateUtils {

    public static LocalDate toLocalDate(Date date) {
        return date == null ? null : date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDate());
    }

}
```

> and make sure that DateUtils is part of Mapper#uses. This way MapStruct will use your custom function to map between Date and LocalDate.

Answer (score 1):

A basic conversion would be

```
 Date date= new Date();
 LocalDateTime localdate= date.toInstant().atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toLocalDateTime();
```

Since you have not posted your conversion  code we don't know what is going on your side.

Comment: Sorry, I'm using a mapper with map struct. I have updated the question. Thanks!

Comment: Instead of `UTC`  can you try to use `default` zone

Answer (score 0):

Fiz utilizando o MapperStruct em uma interface da seguinte forma:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring", unmappedTargetPolicy = ReportingPolicy.IGNORE)
public interface LoyaltyMapper {

default LocalDateTime transactionDateToLocalDateTime(final LocalDate transactionDate) {
    final DateTimeFormatter dateTimeFormatter = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.SSS'Z'");

    final String transactionDateTimeFormatter = transactionDate.atTime(0, 0, 0, 0).format(dateTimeFormatter);
    final LocalDateTime transactionDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(transactionDateTimeFormatter, dateTimeFormatter);
    return transactionDateTime;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for wanting to contribute. It’s unnecessarily complicated and not really correct. It also seems to answer a different question (this one was about converting from an old-fashioned `java.util.Date`). If you just wanted to convert from `LocalDate` to `LocalDateTime` at 00:00, all you need is `return transactionDate.atStartOfDay();` (1 simple line instead of 4).